Use bitwise operator to confirm intA "includes" intB? (e.g. @schema_option in sp_addarticle)
I've generated scripts for our replication publications/subscriptions, and I'd like to confirm whether the sp_addarticle @schema_option param of 0x000000000803509F "contains/includes" the option for nonclustered indexes 0x40. I could watch 100 tutorials on bitwise operations/logic and still not get it. :-)
SELECT CONVERT(INT,0x000000000803509F) | CONVERT(INT,0x40) returns 134435039.
SELECT CONVERT(INT,0x000000000803509F) & CONVERT(INT,0x40) returns 0.
Is that meaningful? Is there a specific, common result value that means "included/contained?" Am I doing this wrong? Appreciate any help. Thanks!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

The first two comments (dupe reference and the post selected as the answer) were deleted here, but thank you all for the help.
